# Ash Complex Variables - complex differentiable at a point

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I am self studying Complex Variables by Ash & Novinger. In [Definition 1.3.1., Chapter 1](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/CV/CV1.pdf), the authors define complex differentiability at point in the following fashion:

Let $f : \Omega \to \mathbb C$ where $\Omega$ is a subset of $\mathbb C$. We say that $f$ is *complex-differentiable* at the point $z_0 \in \mathbb C$ if for some $\lambda \in \mathbb C$, we have
\begin{equation}
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(z_0 + h)-f(z_0)}{h} = \lambda.
\end{equation}

---

Now, if $z_0$ happens to be an isolated point of $\Omega$ then the definition of limit makes no sense. Do the authors mean that $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb C$ or presume $z_0$ to be a limit point of $\Omega$ or am I missing something here?

Comment: I have only ever seen the definition with $\Omega$ open, so you are most likely right

Comment: Later in  the text they say it's open so it's likely just an oversight.

Comment: The function should be defined in a neighborhood of $z_0.$